# Why won't my code output the final print function?

Tags: arrays, swift, printing

Code:

```
bucketList = ["Fly hot air balloon to Fiji", "Watch the LOTR trilogy", "Go on a walkabout", "Scuba dive", "Find a triple rainbow"]

let challenge = bucketList.index(of: "Fly hot air balloon to Fiji")

let offset = challenge! + 2

let finalIndex = bucketList[offset]

print(finalIndex)
```

Comment: What *output* do you expect?

Comment: I want it to print the string that is 2 places later in the array. So ideally the "Go on a walkabout" string.

Comment: The code **does** print *Go on a walkabout* (assuming `bucketList` is declared somewhere else as `[String]`).

Comment: What is it printing now?

Comment: You could really shorten this to `print(2 + bucketList.index(of:...`... But did you attempt to debug your code?

Comment: In the output area, it's just blank. I made everything else thats not involved in this area of the code into a comment in case it was interfering but its still just blank.

Comment: Just add let while declaring bucketList in first line.

Comment: Does the print function work if you print anything else?

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason it was a problem with Xcode; I knew something was wrong when I noticed not even "Hello World" was being printed in the beginning of playground.So I shut  it down and opened it back up and it started working. But thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

so I ran your code, I got an error that `bucketList` is not defined
sooo 
I added `let` before defining `bucketList`
And it worked
the output was

```
"Go on a walkabout"
```